# What's the time complexity of JavaScript spread syntax in arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity, spread

I was wondering what is the time complexity of using spread with an array in JavaScript. Is it linear O(n) or constant O(1)?

Example of syntax below:

```js
let lar = Math.max(...nums)
```

Comment: I don't have any evidence, but it would be quite odd if it wasn't O(n). It has to iterate over every element of the array.

Comment: There is no spread operator, there is [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). ;-)

Comment: @RobG ya sorry about that. Will edit the question :)

Comment: @jhpratt ya at-least it's better to see a clearer picture that's why I asked haha.

Comment: I think it will depend on the alternative you want to compare to and the implementation it's running in, e.g. in the OP, vs `Math.max.apply(null,nums)` and maybe in the case of a host object vs `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p'))` or similar.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Spread calls the `[Symbol.iterator]` property on the object in question. For arrays, this will iterate through every item in the array, calling the array iterator's `.next()` until the iterator is exhausted, resulting in complexity of `O(N)`.

For the exact same reason, `for..of` (which also calls `[Symbol.iterator]`) loops are also `O(N)`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (const item of arr) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

For a live example, see how the following snippet takes *some time* to execute:

```js
const arr = new Array(3e7).fill(null);
const t0 = performance.now();
const arr2 = [...arr];
console.log(performance.now() - t0);
```

(if the operation was `O(1)`, it'd be near instantaneous, but it isn't)

Argument spread is different from array spread, but it uses the [same operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax) (iterates through the iterable until it's exhausted), and so has the same complexity.

> For function calls:
>
> ```
> myFunction(...iterableObj);
> ```

Comment: Just a note that simplistic performance tests like the above are likely heavily influenced by how different implementations do or don't optimise code. Making a change to the operations being performed can have a significant impact on relative performance that far exceeds any differences in `...`, *for..in*, *for..of*, etc. :-)