# Time, space complexity for my JS anagram map solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, hash, anagram

The current setup, `A` and `B` could be larger anagrams but I chose a simple example here.

The goal is to find an index mapping `P`, from `A` to `B`. A mapping `P[i] = j` means the [n]th element in `A` appears in `B` at index `j`.

```
const A = [12, 28, 46, 32, 50]
const B = [50, 12, 32, 46, 28]

const hash = B.reduce((acc,cur,idx) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: idx }), {});

const result = A.reduce((acc,cur) => [...acc, hash[cur]], []);

return result
```

The result should be

```
[1, 4, 3, 2, 0]
```

What I think the time/space complexity for my solution is:
**hash**: time = `O(a)`, space = `O(c)`
**result**: time = `O(b)`, space = `O(d)`
Final answer is time = `O(a + b)`, space = `O(c + d)`
Final final answer for time and space is `O(n)`?

Even though the result is being generated using time `O(1)` because of the `hash`, overall I think the time is `O(n)` cause `n` is the numbers. Am I correct in thinking this?

What is everyone thought on this? (If I'm right or wrong, not sure).

*I figured some of you would ask why not use `indexOf()`, from my research, it looks like under the hood its a loop so I would be running `O(2n)`. So medium to large size anagrams would be fatal.*

Comment: The careless use of the spread operator probably destroys your time and space complexities. Also, it's not a "hash", it's maybe a hashmap, or just a map (also see the built in `Map`). I don't fully understand, what the task for the code is, but what if some numbers occur more than once? What, if it is not an anagram, and there is no `hash[cur]`? What, if they are not even the same length?

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` supposed to represent?

Comment: @ASDFGerte its a find anagram mapping of their indices. Non anagrams aren't given or considered and only anagrams will be given.

Answer (score 2):

The **spread operator** (`...acc`) is [an O(n) operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032373/whats-the-time-complexity-of-javascript-spread-syntax-in-arrays) over the object being spread. This hits your time complexity quite a bit.

Also, since `A` and `B` are anagrams you can use the same symbol `n` for both as they will have the same length.

I'm not sure about space complexity but I think the time complexity will be:

**hash**: time = O(n^2)

**result**: time = O(n^2)

Final answer is time = O(2n^2) which is ~O(n^2).

---

Suggested improvements:

- Don't use spread operator, it's unnecessary and slow.
- `Array.map` instead of `Array.reduce` for the result is much cleaner
- `hash` isn't hashing anything so the name is unclear, it's more of a mapping of numbers to indices - `map` is more clear

```js
const A = [12, 28, 46, 32, 50]
const B = [50, 12, 32, 46, 28]

const map = B.reduce((acc,cur,idx) => { acc[cur] = idx; return acc; }, {});
const result = A.map(cur => map[cur]);

console.log(result);
```

This version is a pretty straightforward O(2n) -> ~O(n).